# jquery file upload 400 bad request

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-3, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to implement jquery file upload on codeigniter following this 
tutorial: https://mevlutcanvar.com.tr/en/integration-tutorial-jquery-file-uploader-9-with-codeigniter-3/239

However upon loading the page I'm getting error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) and noticed that the url is appended with [object%20Object]

Here's my js:

```
$(function () {
'use strict';

$('#fileupload').fileupload({

    url: 'http://localhost/webadmin/admin/product/json'
});

$('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');

$.ajax({

    url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    dataType: 'json',
    context: $('#fileupload')[0]
}).always(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
}).done(function (result) {
    $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
        .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
});
});
```

And on my controller:

```
public function json()
{ 
    $options = [
     'script_url' => site_url('admin/product/json'),
        'upload_dir' => APPPATH . '.../../uploads/files/',
        'upload_url' => site_url('uploads/files/')
     ];

     $this->load->library('UploadHandler', $options);
}
```

I tried to alert the value of $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url') and getting [object object] instead of the url. Am I missing something? Also checked the sequence of declaring js files and make sure doesn't conflict with other plugin. Upload dir and paths are correct and existing.

Comment: _"Am I missing something?"_ <- yes. don't use `alert()` for debugging. Use `console.log()` instead

Comment: Have you read the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) at all? It doesn't look like you're supposed to use `$.ajax()`

Comment: that plugin documentation is for the basic html page only. I want to use the ajax options https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options/ and integrated with codeigniter. I also used console.log for debugging

Comment: As the documentation says, it **makes use of `jQuery.ajax()`**. You do not need to call `$.ajax()` directly as that is what the plugin does

Comment: I have now finally figured it out. I just realized I have put the file upload form inside a form. It's now working.